# How are these PGM files encoded?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, text, pgm

I exported a grayscale image as PGM using MATLAB (and OpenCV) and got this [file](https://pastebin.com/NgnibnLr) as an output.

```
    im = imread(src);
    im = rgb2gray(im);
    imwrite(im, dst);
```

According to the [PGM Specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) the header contains the "magic number", the width, the height, and the max value of the image.

But below the header, there should be a matrix of grayscale intensity values written in plaintext. But as you can see in the pasted file, I just get some kind of junk out (although it's a completely valid, viewable image)

I want to be able to read in the PGM files and access the individual intensity values as integers using a C/C++ program but I don't know how to interpret this output since it doesn't follow the spec. Perhaps the text encoding is different?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: _"below the header, there should be a matrix of grayscale intensity values written in plaintext"_ According to whom?

Comment: You're right - I took the example too literally.

Comment: There's a better description here... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Comment: Do you mean the example in the "Plain PGM" section that describes _"another version of the PGM format that is fairly rare"_? ;) plz2read the whole document not just select parts of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misreading the spec.

> Each gray value is represented in pure binary by either 1 or 2 bytes. If the Maxval is less than 256, it is 1 byte. Otherwise, it is 2 bytes. The most significant byte is first.

So each pixel is either one or two bytes (depending on the Maxval) and in binary, not ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading the definition of the "plain" format (magic number **`P2`**), but you have a "raw" PBM file (magic number **`P5`**).  You might want to pipe through `pnmtopnm -plain` to access ASCII-format encoding.